# Ruby: Finding duplicate array elements in two dimentional array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have this array:

```
a= [[1,2],[3,4],[1,2],[2,3],[2,3]]
```

How can I make user to enter an array element ex:`[1,2]` and it should take that element and return the number of times it is found in the array.

Comment: I cannot parse your sentence.

Comment: Ah, school time again!

Answer (score 2):

You have your array `a` and the user input (i1 and i2), all you have to do is:

```
a.count([i1, i2])
```